# git rewrite history from fast-forward to no-fast-forward

Tags: git, refactoring, rebase

so I've been working on an Android project for a while doing backend & native client development. The project has made some progress from then and I am the only the project committer, so I basically fast-forward-merged everything I added or fixed. Now my company wants a new Android developer and pull me to the back end team. I want to rewrite my android repo history and show what features have been added / fixed / released and all that. So I want my fast-forwarded linear commit history to be re written in a form of non-fast-forwarded type. Is this possibe?

Comment: If you have the reflogs you maybe able to reconstruct some of your flow from there. i.e. by noting when you did the old --ff merges, and replay them (via a scripted rebase) and add a proper merge instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking into the output of `git reflog`, or via `grep`:

```
git reflog --date=iso | grep -i Fast-forward
```

One can find the 'merge' commits resulted from fast forward:

```
b69e480 HEAD@{422}: merge b69e480: Fast-forward
38e2ace HEAD@{438}: merge 38e2ace: Fast-forward
```

Then it should be possible to restore those branches, and re-merge them with `--no-ff` flag, by first re-winding `HEAD` back to the proper start point.

There's [a related blog](https://medium.com/@jdan/seriously-the-reflog-isnt-that-scary-a4189dd88c40#.1i8pfpdlu), demonstrating how to recover a bad merge, which used the same approach, and it might be a good example.